# Restrict access to the Package Installation Wizard

Tags: sitecore-client, content-management, packages

We would like to restrict access to the Package Installation Wizard within a test environment.

This is to ensure all Sitecore items are being correctly deployed from serialisation data.

Can this be achieved with security permissions?

Can the Package Installation Wizard be disabled via configuration?

Comment: I tried the following steps in SC 82.: - create new role called Package Manager - Assign read and inheritance to new role for Package Designer - Assign new role to user When I log into SC as user, I initially did not see Developer Tools folder, so added read to that for Package Manager role as well. Now I can see Developer Tools folder in right menu, but the only app is Keyboard Map - which I've not set any explicit permissions. I'm pretty stumped tbh ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can adjust the security rights In the core database
item:

> /sitecore/content/Documents and settings/All users/Start
>   menu/Right/Development Tools/Install Package

default: read right for sitecore\Sitecore Client Developing

You can remove that right, see the Security Field of that item. Than only the admin has access to the Package installation wizard, or set the right that are suitable for you.

Comment: Thanks. What about the Install a Package link within the Administration section in the Control Panel?